How to Render PUA and EUDC Characters Correctly in WPF?
I am working on a WPF (.NET 8) application that needs to display special characters from PUA (Private Use Area) and EUDC (Extended User Defined Characters). However, I am encountering issues with rendering them correctly. The characters either do not appear at all or are rendered incorrectly.
If I set the font like this:
<TextBox FontFamily="C:\\WINDOWS\\FONTS\\EUDC.TTE#EUDC" FontSize="23" />

it displays correctly. However, this seems like a strange solution to me. This method does not work with RichEdit either. Is there another way to display EUDC characters?
<Window
    x:Class="FONTTESTWPF.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="800"
    Height="450"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Margin="0" Orientation="Vertical">
            <TextBlock
                Margin="7"
                FontSize="18"
                Text="RichTextBox:" />

            <!--  Does not display characters  -->
            <RichTextBox
                Margin="7,0,7,0"
                FontFamily="C:\\WINDOWS\\FONTS\\EUDC.TTE#EUDC"
                FontSize="23" />

            <TextBlock
                Margin="7"
                FontSize="18"
                Text="TextBox:" />

            <!--  Displays characters  -->
            <TextBox
                Margin="7,0,7,0"
                FontFamily="C:\\WINDOWS\\FONTS\\EUDC.TTE#EUDC"
                FontSize="23" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>

Example

maybe this will help? https://www.trycatchdebug.net/news/1275588/displaying-pua-eudc-characters-in-wpf in general I run your code and didnt encounter any issue which you are describing
